# Actionscript create a value object from Json

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a large json file that I pass to actionscript and I want generate a value object.

What is the best way of doing this? Actually I was trying with this code:

```
    public function Report(data:Object)
    {
        if(data.SCORE){
            this.score = data.SCORE;
        }

        if(data.TITLE){
            this.title = new Object();
            this.title.response = data.TITLE.TEXT;
        }
    }
```

Doing this for more than 100 json property would be tedious. So How can I create a value object from json?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [JSON](http://help.adobe.com/ru_RU/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/JSON.html) class' [`parse`](http://help.adobe.com/ru_RU/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/JSON.html#parse%28%29) method, like this:

```
var myJson:Object = JSON.parse( data );
```

After this your `myJson` object is common object with a data. No need in duplicate values from one object to another..

Comment: I got Error #1132: Invalid JSON parse input.

Comment: @Tropicalista hmm , may be something wrong with your json file , take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11705060/json-parse-error-1132-invalid-json-parse-input-flex-actionscript-php

Comment: JSON.parse need a string, I'm passing an object

Comment: @Tropicalista if so , what exactly you're trying to achieve? why you need to duplicate stuff ?

Comment: @Tropicalista yeah , you can directly use this big data object in all your classes by making him public , you know