# Java actionscript Socket connection large json string error parsing because not all data is passed

Tags: java, sockets, actionscript

I'am passing a large json string between java and as3, but when the string gets really BIG, then not all the data is retrieved, and I get parse errors, has anyone some idea on how to solve this?

actionscript error in try catch:

```
Error #1132
```

Comment: May be this is relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11705060/json-parse-error-1132-invalid-json-parse-input-flex-actionscript-php

Comment: my json string is correct, but is too large, thats the problem, but all the data of there is required, I don't know how to pass all this data

Comment: can we somehow see your json ?

Comment: Split the data into various json chunks and then make several calls to the server. This will also lead to a smoother performance on the client. Considering AMF can also be an option. Since you're using a Java backend, BlazeDS can be a good alternative to JSON.